# como tomar un elemento en especifico de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando tomar un elemento en especifico de un arreglo para después utilizarlo en un titulo de una tabla.

Lo estoy intentando hacer de esta forma:

```js
if (this.parametros['tipoSerie'] == this.tiposSerie['DIARIA']['id']) {
  let tituloApi = this.listadoResultado[0];
  let array = JSON.stringify(tituloApi).split(' ');
  let tituloDes = array[0];
  console.log(tituloDes);
  console.log(tituloApi);
  this.columnasGrilla.push({
    header: 'Fecha',
    field: 'fecha'
  });
  this.columnasGrilla.push({
    header: 'tituloDes',
    field: 'monto_moneda_norm'
  });
```

Donde guardo el valor en una variable y luego intento de recuperar el valor en especifico. Estoy trabajando con angular

[image: Imagen de la tabla]

Answer (score 0):

Era mas sencillo de lo que pensaba.

simplemente acceder a la propiedad del objeto

```
let tituloApi = this.listadoResultado[0].pro_des;
        console.log(tituloApi);
        this.columnasGrilla.push({ header: 'Fecha', field: 'fecha' });
        this.columnasGrilla.push({ header: tituloApi, field: 'monto_moneda_norm' });
```